# Issue to combine the Clueweb09 annotation data and Freebase dump data

Tags: freebase

I am using [Freebase dump data](https://developers.google.com/freebase/data) to use RDFs and combine it with the [annotation ClueWeb09 data](http://lemurproject.org/clueweb09/FACC1/). But, I face with the following problem:

> clueweb09-en0000-00-00011 ISO-8859-1  English language    17964   17980   0.999813    0.000165    **/m/02h40lc**

But, when I read Freebase dump data with (Java & Ubuntu)the mid is mentioned **/m.02h40lc** when I read the gz file. I want to know that I did something wrong OR I should change **/m.02h40lc** to **/m/02h40lc** manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to replace all slashes (/) in identifiers with periods (.) when working with the current data dumps.  This transformation was necessary to make URIs containing the identifiers work properly.  This is true not only for MIDs, but also other identifiers used for types, namespaces, etc.  For example, type/object/name becomes type.object.name in the data dump.